# UWP | Popup width and height

Tags: c#, uwp, window

I created a simple popup like below

```
<Grid>
    <Popup VerticalOffset="0" HorizontalOffset="0" x:Name="StandardPopup" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" 
                Background="Red"
                BorderThickness="0">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Simple Popup" FontSize="10.667"/>
                    <Button Content="Close" Click="ClosePopupClicked"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
</Grid>
```

However, when I query it's size, is coming as (w, h) = (220, 480). This looks like an incorrect size, as it is rendered very small. I have read about placement of popup etc, but cannot understand how to find the true correctly rendered size of a popup.

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. What's the behavior you expected? Is the popup size too small or too big?

Comment: Do you query (ActualWidth, ActualHeight) or just (Width, Height) properties? The former returns the actual size of the popup while the later return the size that has been set to the properties which might be different that the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the content's width and height of `Popup`, eg,

```
<Border Width="360" Height="200">

</Border>
```

Otherwise, the size of `Popup` will auto fit its content.

See more doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup?view=winrt-18362