# How to reliably get actual dimensions of a UWP Popup?

Tags: windows, uwp, popup, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP App which contains a Page which has 4 Popups defined on it. Each Popup is data-bound to a separate Boolean in the View Model. By manipulating the VM, I can make any of the 4 popus appear - only 1 at a time - maximum.

I would like to control where these Popups appear, so I've added "Opened" event handlers to each of them. The event handlers do the appropriate math to calculate Vertical & HorizontalOffset for the Popups.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486695/uwp-popup-width-and-height), which was never answered is my problem as well. To explain it better, querying the popups ActualWidth/Height gives nonsense values. All of my popups are different sizes but all are landscape (width > height). I consistently get ActualWidth=310 & ActualHeight=779 for all of them.

By using the Popup's Child's dimensions (always a Grid) in the math, 2 of the 4 work consistently; the other 2 sometimes work, but usually not. EDIT: They fail because the Grid has no dimensions.

I'm assuming the Opened event is as late as possible to allow all Layout / Measures to occur. Short of hard-coding Heights & Widths on the Popups (one of which will have variable content), I've run out of stuff to try.

There's a lot of code, but they're virtually identical. This is one of the ones that  works intermittently ...

```
            <Popup  x:Name="LoserTool"
                IsOpen="{x:Bind vm.bLoseTool, Mode=OneWay}"
                Opened="Popup_Opened"
                >

                <Grid   x:Name="gLoserTool"
                    Background="{StaticResource TaipanHunter_Primary_Dark}"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource TaipanHunter_Primary_Light}"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    Padding="20"
                    RowSpacing="10">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock  Text="Oh No!"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource TaipanHunter_Title}"
                        />
                    <TextBlock  Text="Your tool broke!"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource Text_LightText}"
                        />
                    <Button Content="Play Again"
                        Click="StartNewGame"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{StaticResource Button_Base}"
                        />

                </Grid>

            </Popup>
```

Comment: Can you manually set the width and height for the Popup in xam?

Comment: For 3 of them, yes. The fourth is trickier as it has variable content. I just don't understand why the Popups are reporting incorrect values. Is there a possibility that they're reporting the aggregate size of all 4 of them?

Comment: I'd suggest you manually set the width and height for the Popups. The variable content might be the reason for the 4th one compared with the other 3 popups.

Comment: I haven't actually implemented the variable content yet. I'm seeing 3 problems. ActualHeaight / Width reporting bogus values; SizeChanged will NEVER fire on a Popup and sometimes the Child Actual sizes report zero. I can design around these failings, and I will to get my App working, but really?????????

Comment: I merged 3 of the Popups into a single one (i.e. went from 4 on the Page to 2). It worked a little better - but not well enough to ship. There were still intermittent placement issues. In the end I changed the design to re-use something I'd done on a previous product and which I knew worked reliably.